# UEFI installation failed Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, partition, boot-loader, uefi

I have installed Windows 8.1 on my Lenovo laptop. When I configure partitions I receive this error:

```
No valid bootloader target device found. 
For UEFI installation , you must include an EFI System Partition on a 
GPT-formatted disk, mounted at /boot/efi.
```

And here is a picture with partitions which I was make:

[image]

Comment: It's just their psycho installer. `chroot` to the disk you just installed the rest and finish setting it up.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Might be just `grub-install` (with no args); see also this fine document: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I experienced a similar issue which CentOS 7. Try to partition everything with another linux (install) media (gparted or arch for example) and then just enter the mountpoints and filesystems but not click on `reformat`